# .NET WebClient - Upload data and get stream

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, webclient

I have a situation where I want to asynchronously write a series of bytes with WebClient (in much the same way as UploadDataAsync) and get a readable response stream (in the same way as OpenReadAsync).

You seem to be able to do the two individually, but not both of them together. Is there a way?

Comment: Try using HttpWebRequest? Slightly more complicated but it allows you to do both

Comment: I've just ported all my code from using HttpWebRequest to WebClient (for simplicities sake... oops :p)

Comment: The problem is that you've got a *relatively* complex requirement - and WebClient is a simple way of doing simple things - but it doesn't handle more complicated scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that [UploadDataTaskAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138525.aspx) will do what you want. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736471/56778 for an example.