# Async HTTP Post data in single function using Async CTP

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-ctp

I'm trying use Async CTP to build single function that run async and return a value.

here is my sample code. i don't know why it dont fill the "resp" variable at return.

```
public async Task<string> sendRequest(string url, string postdata)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    client.UploadDataAsync(uri,"POST", data);
    string resp = "";
    await TaskEx.Run(()=>
    client.UploadDataCompleted += (e, s) =>
    {
        resp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(s.Result);
    });
    return resp;
}
```

Also I tried this but the program freeze ( do nothing more not just for a while ). maybe any correction can help.

```
public async Task<string> sendRequest(string url, string postdata)
{
    string resp = "";
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    data = await TaskEx.Run(()=>client.UploadData(uri,"POST", data));

    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
}
```

Comment: You're subscribing to the event, after you start the upload. This means you have a race condition.

Comment: Two races in fact - the one @CodeInChaos mentions, and then your last `await` is waiting until you're *subscribed* to the event - but no guarantee that the event has actually happened.

Answer (score 7):

You could, instead, use the `UploadDataTaskAsync` extension method (part of the CTP), and not have to write that plumbing code yourself:

```
public async Task<string> sendRequest(string url, string postdata)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    resp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(await client.UploadDataTaskAsync(uri,"POST", data));
    return resp;
}
```

The implementation of that extension method handles the event subscription correctly, and ensures that the task is completed when the event actually fires.

Comment: You done this as parallel to me. i mentioned , the program will freeze at the "await".

Comment: @ShirazITCo - then the url that you're `POST`ing this data to isn't responding - that's nothing to do with the async code (but would indicate that the original fault was the second one identified - your original method is returning before the `UploadDataCompleted` method fires - it never actually fires).

Comment: @ShirazITCo: Are you doing a blocking `Wait` or `Result` at some point? If you change `await client.UploadDataTaskAsync(..)` to `await client.UploadDataTaskAsync(..).ConfigureAwait(false)` does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to `UploadDataCompleted` before you start the upload. Not sure if that's responsible for your problem, but it is a bug that can lead to `resp` not being set.

Comment: @ShirazITCo Even if it is not responsible for your immediate problem, it is still a bug.